What is largest file size of picture and cost of such a camera?
If we have 4k screen my smartphone images are 4MB. But do SLRs have higher space occupation and what is the best? Can we make an image 100 Mb - 1 Gb and will be clearer?
Where can I buy such cameras and take videos and pictures? So that I can fill 10 Tb drives and share on DC++ or cloud.

Based on the title, do you mean the single camera with the largest number of pixels?  And how much money do you have /s

How much are you willing to spend? The budget of a small country will get you a lot more than any typical consumer oriented product.

The relation between file size (i.e 4MB) and image resolution (i.e. 4K) is not fixed. It depends upon scene contents, file format, and data compression. Scenes with more details will have larger file size at the same resolution and compression than scenes with fewer details. A solid black or solid white image can be very small in terms of file size and be very large in terms of resolution because all of the pixels have the same value.

And what does "DC++ and 10 Tb" drives have to do with anything?  Also if you can "terabyte", then the correct nomenclature is "TB" and not "Tb"

I'm voting to close this as "question needs more details/info". This reads like an X→Y problem. What photographic task do you wish to accomplish? What solutions have you tried and why do you find them unacceptable?

Do you mean megapixels (MP)?
